# Missing OOTB crawled properties in SharePoint 2013 Search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, crawled-property

We have SharePoint 2013 and we have noticed that we are missing the following Out of the Box (OOTB) search crawled properties:

**ows_EndDate**

**ows_Last_x0020_modified**

What would be the best way to resolve the issue without adding the properties manually via PowerShell? Also, we would rather not reset the index if there is another way to resolve or troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I can't find that in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630(v=office.15).aspx. Do you have a link or documentation talking about `ows_Last_x200_modified`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware of that is not an OOTB crawled property.  If it was I imagine you would be looking for `ows_Last_x0020_Modified` instead of `ows_Last_x200_modified`.

What I see for the modified fields are (Managed Property : Crawled Properties):

`ModifiedBy` :  `ows_ModifiedBy`, `ows_Modified_x0020_By`, `LastModifiedBy`

`LastModifiedTime` :  `LastSavedDateTime`, `Basic:14`, `Basic:16`

`ModifiedOWSDATE` :  `ows_q_DATE_Modified`

EDIT:

Looking through the existing crawled properties I have found `ows__EndDate` (Notice the double underscore) and `ows_Last_x0020_Modified`.  Both of these are NOT tied to a managed property by default.

To check to see if you have them set up the same go to `Site Settings` -> `Site Collection Administration` -> `Search Schema`.  At the top of the page click `Crawled Properties` and search for them.  If you find them you can click into it and map it to a managed property.

Comment: You may have already done this as you said you are missing them, but I updated my answer for you to check to verify they are actually missing as a crawled property.  For your scenario would you be able to use either `LastModifiedTime` or `ModifiedOWSDATE`?